# Re-show my main Cocoa application Window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow

Ok, as simple and silly as that may seem, this is my scenario :

- The application window (there is just ONE main window) is minimized
- The user clicks something on the dock menu
- We want to bring that main window back

Simple?

Not quite.

I've tried accessing my main window via :

- `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] mainWindow]`
- `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows]`

and then sending a `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` message but it's simply NOT showing up.

I've even tried showing all windows (yep, it still sees as "windows" one-or-two (hidden) sheets I'm using...), but still nothing.

Could you suggest a way, I could finally show that window, WITHOUT having to set an outlet anywhere?

I don't know; I'm probably too tired to notice, but this thing is almost nerve-wrecking...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can un-minimize a window like so:

```
if([aWindow isMiniaturized])
{
   [aWindow deminiaturize:self];
}
```

However, the problem is that the window will lose main status when it is minimized, so you'll need some other way of identifying the window.

Why can't you just use an outlet?

You can make the app un-minimize all of its minimized windows like so:

```
for(NSWindow* win in [NSApp windows])
{
    if([win isMiniaturized])
    {
        [win deminiaturize:self];
    }
}
```

When the app launches, you could store a reference to the main window and register for the `NSWindowDidMiniaturizeNotification`. That will tell you when the main window minimizes, which might also help you.

Comment: Well, I'm working on quite a large project (like 100,000 lines of code, or even more) and although the code is almost cleaned up, there are still some issues with the interface; (and some instances actually not properly release - that's what I'm putting the blame on, at least). However, your last trick (looping through windows and just `deminiaturize`ing the `miniaturized` ones) worked. (I know it's not perfect; but it's one of those times that you really NEED to see some little bit working and move ahead (even though I'll most likely get back at some point to refine it)). Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: I wasted too much time for this and finally i got solution. Thank You Rob Keniger. :)